# HTML/CSS/JS build tool

Tags: javascript, css, ant, build, minify

I have a project which consist of a lot of static HTML and js files. I need a build tool that can concatenate and minify them.

I saw [this](http://vimeo.com/21278421) great screencast that explains how to do it with ant and YUI. The only thing I'm missing is after the minified version is created , how can i replace references to the JS/CSS files in the HTML, so it will reference the new minified version?

Is there a better/easier tool for this (**not GPL/LGPL license**)?

Comment: Why not GPL/LGPL?  You probably won't need to modify something like this, so there is no viral licensing to worry about.

Comment: I work at a large company that forbids the use of that license.

Comment: @ftom2 don't tell them that by merely asking this question on the Internet you're using vast quantities of GPL software :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt) is pretty good, and supports most of those things. [This plugin](https://github.com/izb/grunt-consolidate-css) will re-write your CSS link tags, though normally (and for JS) you'd just write the link/script tags to point straight to the minified version anyway, and continually have it build your files.

Comment: `you'd just write the link/script tags to point straight to the minified version anyway` - not sure i understand, I have many css/js files and i want them concatenated to just one file. how can reference it before it exists?

Comment: Because you never view the file you're editing - you only ever view the built version of your site, where the concatenated files do exist. Grunt can run continuously to keep the files in sync while you work

Comment: So there are also 2 HTML versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [minify JS and CSS](http://jscompress.com/). Minify JS can make 1 JS file merging multiple JS file and same for CSS.